# What is wrong with self-modifying codes with static-recompilation emulations?

Tags: emulation, virtualization, self-modifying

I was searching for writing an emulator, and its techniques. But following paragraph made me wondered, I think I couldn't figure out which scenario can be present, if you write a self-modifying code to be static-recompilation emulated.

> In this technique, you take a program written in the emulated code and attempt to translate it into the assembly code of your computer. The result will be a usual executable file which you can run on your computer without any special tools. While static recompilation sounds very nice, it is not always possible. For example, you cannot statically recompile self-modifying code as there is no way to tell what it will become without running it. To avoid such situations, you may try combining static recompiler with an interpreter or a dynamic recompiler.

Here is what I was reading, and this line made me wondered:

> For example, you cannot statically recompile self-modifying code as there is no way to tell what it will become without running it

A good explanation with examples will be so instructive, thanks.

Edit: By the way, I know the meaning of self-modifying, I just wonder what problems and where will we get problems after statically-recompilation, which thing will make our self-modifying code broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-modifying code heavily relies on the instruction set encoding of the original CPU. For example, it could flip some bits in a specific memory location to turn one instruction into another. With static recompilation, flipping those same bits will have an entirely different effect since the instructions are encoded completely differently for the host CPU.